# Windows Phone Emulator won't launch

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

The emulator used to run fine, but as of late whenever i try to launch it, whether directly from the programs list or by running code in Visual Studio, the emulator will launch, stop responding and crash, then when I hit "close program" it will launch itself again, stop responding and crash again.  I've looked everywhere and cannot get an answer to this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way i think is by **reinstalling the product**.
Just so you know, make sure that you're using the right version of the SDK for your OS (on PC) and using just the right emulator supported by your OS (pc).

Like for SDK 8.0, if you're developing Win8 app, use 'Device' for direct app deployment onto your phone or "Emulator WVGA 512MB" for optimized, memory-constrained output on your PC itself.